# I am getting null pointer exception for following program

Tags: java, session, variables, if-statement, nullpointerexception

```
    /*line 1.*/ 
    if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!(name.equals("")||address.equals("")))){


        sessionNameModel.setObject(""+name);
        sessionAddressModel.setObject(""+address);
        add(sessionName);
        add(sessionAddress);

    }
    else{
        sessionNameModel.setObject("");
        sessionAddressModel.setObject("");
        add(sessionName);
        add(sessionAddress);

    }
```

I am getting null pointer exception in line 1. I know the value of name and address field is null but i have to check in cases when session updates the value. i need to know how to check these variables name and address as null or not..

Comment: You could quite probably get rid of the if statement and use a ternary. sessionNameModel.setObject(name == null ? "" : name.toString());

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that your condition is correct, change:

```
if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!(name.equals("")||address.equals("")))){
```

to:

```
if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!("".equals(name)||"".equals(address)))){
```

**Explanation:**
by using `"".equals(name)` you guarantee that even if `name` is `null` (which is possible since you're using `||` in the previous expression) the comparison will return false instead of NPE. Same goes for `address`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!(name.equals("")||address.equals(""))))
```

Here if `name==null` still you are checking for `name.equals` which may cause nullpointer same thing happens for address.Instead use `&&` for checking equals only if it's not null.Or you can use `"".equals`  as suggested by `alfasin`

```
if((name!=null && !name.equals(""))||((address!=null && !address.equals(""))))
```

---

*Apart  from the discussion,*

I think here use of `||` not needed instead use `&&` as here `||` can add `null` in your session which is not proper.

```
if((name!=null && !name.equals(""))&&((address!=null && !address.equals(""))))
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try like this**

```
if((name !=null || name.length()==0) && (address!=null || address.length()==0)){

}
else{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
name = null;
address = null;

if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!(name.equals("")||address.equals(""))))
```

Analysis;
first checks `name!=null`, it's **false**
then checks `address!=null`, which is **false** either
then it tries to check if `name.equals("")`, but since **name** is null, it will crash because there is no object as **name** and so no method as **equals**

as looking at the other lines you have to change the line as

```
if((name!=null && address!=null)&&(!(name.equals("")||address.equals(""))))
```

Let's analyse the new line;
first checks `name!=null`, which is **false**
since all other conditions are combined with **AND** and since one of them is **false**, no need to check anything else, so executes the second line

Answer (score 1):

At first cobait is right:

```
if((name!=null || address!=null)||(!(name.equals("")||address.equals(""))))
```

If either the variable name or the variable address is null, the following code will still be executed. This is probably causing your nullpointer.

Better expression would be `if((name != null) && (address != null)) ....`

If you want to execute the code for at least for one of the variables, if it is not null, you should split your if statements.

Another alternative for your check would be using the [apache commons library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) and call the function `isBlank()`. This function checks both, if the String is not null and if it's not emtpy.